# Problem on combinatorics solving by using invariance principle

Tags: combinatorics

2015 ones are written in a row..It is allowed to delete any two written numbers a and b and is replaced by a+b/4 the process is continued as long as one number remains or the number is less than .0001.Prove that the last number is greater than .0001

Comment: '2015 ones', i.e. $1111...1$ 2015 times?

Comment: I don't quite understand; can you give an example of what a valid operation on the $2015$ ones is? Can $a$ and $b$ only be $1$, or can $a = 11$ and $b = 111$, for example?

Comment: At the end you say "or the number is less than $.0001$".  Does that mean any number less than $0.0001$ is removed, or you stop if any number is less than $0.0001?$.  We already stopped if we were down to one number.

Comment: A trivial answer, even if we can group $1$s into a single number, is that every number on the list is at least $1$.  The operation $a+\frac b4$ results in a number greater than $a$, so greater than $1$.  You will never get below $1$, let alone $0.0001$.  Why does this fail?

Comment: @Ross: I wonder if *as long as* should have been *until*, and the operation $(a+b)/4$.

Comment: It is one of the question in lativian mathematics site

Comment: Hint given Invariant - - the inverse of all recorded numbers is always less than or equal to 2015

Comment: Stop if number is less than .0001

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that at some point the sum of the reciprocals is $S$. When you replace $a$ and $b$ with $\frac14(a+b)$, the sum of the reciprocals becomes

$$\begin{align*}
S-\frac1a-\frac1b+\frac4{a+b}&=S-\left(\frac{a+b}{ab}-\frac4{a+b}\right)\\
&=S-\frac{(a+b)^2-4ab}{ab(a+b)}\\
&=S-\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab(a+b)}\\
&\le S\;.
\end{align*}$$

Initially $S=2015$, so throughout the procedure we must have $S\le 2015$, and it follows that the last remaining number is at least $\frac1{2015}>0.0001$.